# alpine.js, how to make element disappear on self @click?

Tags: onclick, hide, alpine.js

I want this element to self hide once clicked. How do I target self with Alpine, and string 2 @click events together?

```
<div @click="tagify.addTags(['hardware'])">hardware</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can handle this,

you can target self by the `event.target` as in `method 1`, other methods a just alternative approaches to hide the element.

Method 1 - Set the style inline in the click handler

```html
<div @click="tagify.addTags(['hardware']); event.target.style.display='none';">hardware</div>
```

Method 2 - Use `x-ref`

```html
<div x-ref="hardware" @click="tagify.addTags(['hardware']); $refs.hardware.style.display='none';">hardware</div>
```

Method 3 - Use `x-show` with a variable

```html
<div x-data="{showHardware : true}">
    ....
    <div x-show="showHardware" @click="tagify.addTags(['hardware']); showHardware = false">hardware</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Presumably, only option 3 would allow a transition too?

Comment: yes, I think the transition will work when we use the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me

```
<button @click="open = true; event.target.style.display='none';" x-text="'Show more'"></button>
```